# issue in encoding a string with percent escaping iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsstring, nsurl

This is my string.

```
NSString *str=@"A & B";
```

now i am converting it to NSUTF8StringEncoding.

```
str = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"str: %@", str);
```

space is replaced with %20 but & is not replaced with %26.

nslog show

```
str: A%20&%20B
```

This is also not working

```
NSString *str=@"(A) & (B)";
str = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"str: %@", str);
```

nslog show

```
str: (A)%20&%20(B)
```

I need this because i have to pass this as parameter value in webservice.
Anybody have idea for this. Please help me for this issue. Nice answer will be appreciated

Comment: That process is called *URL Encoding*, and has nothing to do with UTF-8. I also didn't get what your actual question was?

Comment: Thanks for answering trojanfoe. Yes, i acctuly want the url encoding. I mentioned that "I need this because i have to pass this as parameter value in webservice."

Comment: And yet the title of your question doesn't mention it and you don't actually say what the issue is you are having.

Comment: Yes, you are most definitely *not* "converting it to NSUTF8StringEncoding". You are adding percent escapes, using UTF-8 for *their* encoding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes()` to do that:

```
NSString *string = ...;
NSString *encodedString = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
```

Comment: And how does `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes()` differ from `[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]`?

Comment: Well, you can pass a string of characters that you want to escape. ;)