# How to create a URL when query parameters contains &?

Tags: ios, iphone, rest, url, ios7

This question is not specific to `iOS` but since I am developing the application in `iOS`, I see this issue.

I create the `URL` as

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *transactionsUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@/%i/%i?categoryGroup=%@",
                                                       appUrl, @"rest/transactions", [userDefaults valueForKey:kMemberId], year, month, [categoryGroup stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"getting transactions for URL:%@", transactionsUrl);
```

My query parameter `categoryGroup` could be one of the following values

`A & B`, `B & C`,
what I see on `iOS client logs is

```
2014-12-31 21:38:44.654 myapp-ios[41275:70b] getting transactions for URL:https://myapp.com/rest/transactions/78f7f8a4-a8c9-454a-93a8-6633a1076781/2014/12?categoryGroup=A%20&%20B
```

But on server, I see

```
categoryGroup=A
```

so the entire queryParameter is not received on the server.

What could be the potential issue?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/8088484/963195

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the parameters:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

The "&" becomes `%26`.

Comment: That's what he's trying to do with `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`, the problem is that method just doesn't do what it's ostensibly supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

`&` separates GET parameters. Technically, on the server you're seeing `categoryGroup` = `"A "` ("A" followed by a space).

The underlying problem is that `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` doesn't escape things that it should (and does escape things it shouldn't), like `&`. 
Use  `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` instead, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15132728/900873)

> ```
> NSString *encodedString = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
> ```